# Cannot connect to host

Tags: java, nginx, jetty

I've been trying to set up nginx as a proxy to jetty. I have one laptop running ubuntu server. Now I made jetty working at localhost:8080 and it serves the home page for the app at `http://192.168.1.5:8080/my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone/`.

I configured nginx like this ([I adapted it from this page](http://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/1mrsmx/whats_the_common_way_to_use_ring/ccciqhx)):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name nomilkfor.me;
  rewrite ^(.+?)/?$ http://nomilkfor.me$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.nomilkfor.me;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @my-webapp;
  }

  location @my-webapp {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
```

And I can connect to nginx from my home network and I see the nginx welcome screen.

I also tried `$ udo netstat -tanpl|grep nginx`.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3264/nginx: worker
```

I see that nginx is listening at port 80, but when I try to load `nomilkfor.me` I get the "Chrome could not connect to nomilkfor.me" error.

What am I doing wrong?

I created a very simple configuration, and this one too servers the `index.html` in `/usr/share/nginx/` instead of the app through jetty:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nomilkfor.me;

    # access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location /html { 
        root /usr/share/nginx/;
    }
}
```

It seems that nginx is using another conf file than I think. I added a typo to the conf file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/nomilkfor.me` (I removed a closing curly brace) and ran `$ nginx -s reload` and it compiled without error and showed the nginx splash page on the browser. Can there be another conf file somewhere? Is there a way to find which conf file nginx is using?

Comment: does this server live @ it's public ip address, or is on your local lan using 192.168.X  if the latter you need to port forward through you firewall, and even then depending upon firewall you might not be able to access it from local due to firewall's inability to hairpin (Depends on firewall)

Comment: How can I tell if the server lives at its public ip address? I bought a static ip address (because they were blocking port 80). But at this point I am confused. How can I check?

Comment: Ok so you have a static on your Internet connection. You will need to forward the ports via your router/modem to the internal server that is hosting them

Comment: @Doon: Thanks! That was the issue. What happened was that, I did the port forwarding last week, and the last digit was 5, now it changed to 7. Is this normal? Why did it change? But now I have another problem: instead of seeing the home page of the app I see the nginx home page. Why is that? It looks like there is something wrong with my conf file.

Comment: @Doon So nginx is serving the `index.html` here: `/usr/share/nginx/html`. So that would be the first server: `listen 80;
  server_name www.nomilkfor.me;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;` How come it is serving that page first?

Comment: I forgot to create the symlink to `/etc/nginx/sites-enables`. Now it connects but I am still not sure if the page is served by jetty. When I try `http://www.nomilkfor.me/` I get a 404 page with `No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:
/my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@37426497{/my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone.war-_my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone.....` When I click the contexts link the site opens with `http://www.nomilkfor.me/my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone/`

Comment: this is probably better on superuser / maybe serverfault. That error looks like it is getting sent to jetty, I don't know much about jetty but do you need a host header or the like to make it know which context to put you in.  try something like this in nginx config `proxy_set_header Host $host;`